# How to make solr suggestion case insensitive in solr 4.8?

Tags: solr

I downloaded solr 4.8.1 and try with the example. I was able to see suggestion but the suggestion is case sensitive.

For example:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/suggest?suggest.dictionary=mySuggester&suggest=true&suggest.build=true&suggest.q=e
```

--> returns result as expected.

But this:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/suggest?suggest.dictionary=mySuggester&suggest=true&suggest.build=true&suggest.q=E
```

--> doesn't return any result

How can I make it so that the q=E also return the same results as the above query.

Thanks,

Comment: What I see here is that  you are searching for a particular character in your query String , of a particular case. What I did to perform search is that I specified my query like: q=*e* and with the property request handler for suggest inside solrconfig.xml. With this, I was able to find out all occurrences of E, no matter where it is coming and in what case.